# How to get minimum values key from hash in Perl

Tags: perl, hash, minimum

I have script which is able to pick minimum value from hash values.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use List::Util qw(min);

my @array = qw/50 51 52 53 54/;

my $time = 1596561300;

my %hash;

foreach my $element(@array){  
    $hash{$time} = $element;
    $time += 6; #based on some condition incrementing the time to 6s
}

print Dumper(\%hash);

my $min = min values %hash; 
print "min:$min\n";
```

Here I am able to get `50` as a minimum value out of all the values in hash values. But how would I also get the hash key that corresponds to the minimum value, i.e.,`1596561300`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the key, you can get the value. So you want the key with the minimal associated value.

`min LIST` can be written as `reduce { $a <= $b ? $a : $b } LIST`, so we can use

```perl
use List::Util qw( reduce );

my $key = reduce { $hash{$a} <= $hash{$b} ? $a : $b } keys %hash;
my $val = $hash{$key};
```

or

```
my ($key) = keys(%hash);
my $val = $hash{$key};
for (keys(%hash)) {
   if ($hash{$_} < $val) {
      $key = $_;
      $val = $hash{$val};
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See the answer by @ikegami for the cleanest, fastest solution to the exact question of the OP.
If you need to access other keys in the order sorted by values *numerically* (I assume from your example that this is what you want), use this:

```
my @keys_sorted_by_value = sort { $hash{$a} <=> $hash{$b} } keys %hash;

# key with min value: $keys_sorted_by_value[0]
# ...
# key with max value: $keys_sorted_by_value[-1]
```

Or sorted by values *ASCIIbetically*:

```
my @keys_sorted_by_value = sort { $hash{$a} cmp $hash{$b} } keys %hash;
```